# Can the Android NDK access screen graphics?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm looking into the Android NDK. I would like to create an application with a long running service that could record and/or stream the Android's screen graphics at any time. I know this is not possible with a regular application but I'm not sure if the NDK can do this either? For an example of this functionalities usage, I'd like developers to be able to demonstrate an application straight from the Android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the NDK can not do anything more than can be done with the SDK.

Comment: In general no.  But some vendor-specific builds have exposed additional unprivileged interfaces.